# Subsonic many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I have 3 tables, one is called `Users`, one is called `Categories` and one is a linking table called `User_Categories_Map` to link users to categories in a many-to-many relationship.  The linking table consists of `UserId's` and `CategoryId's`.  After generating the subsonic classes, I would assume I'd be able to then type `User.singleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1).Categories` to select all the categories for a user.  However, this doesn't work.  If you can understand what I'm trying to accomplish here, can anyone tell me how I can make this work in subsonic?  Consequently, I cannot find any documentation on subsonic.  Subsonicproject.com only has a short page a few articles about how to set it up.  Is there documentation somewhere for subsonic?

Answer (score 1):

```
int lUserID =1;    // suppose 1 is Id of user

CategoriesCollection lCategories = DB.Select().From<Categories>()  
  .InnerJoin(User_Categories_Map)  
  .InnerJoin(Users)  
  .Where(Users.Columns.Id).IsEqualTo(lUserID)  
  .ExecuteAsCollection<CategoriesCollection>();
```

It will return collection of categories associated to a specific user..